Flutter Pass the self to the click?
Not sure exactly how to ask, but this is kind of my code (but it doesn't work)
   Expanded(
          child: selectedTab == 0
              ? ListView(
            children: [
              WebCard(
                date: 'June 11, 2024',
                time: '10AM-11AM',
                title: 'Blank',
                subTitle: 'GoToBlankPage',
                url: '',
                onCustomJoin: () => openpage(context, this),
              ),
              WebCard(
                date: 'June 12, 2024',
                time: '1PM-2PM',
                title: 'Brugal',
                subTitle: 'Brugal Rum',
                url: 'https://www.brugal.com',
                onCustomJoin: () => openpage(context, this),
              ),
            ],
          )


But the this is a ScreenState and not the WebCard with the link...
I have a feeling I have everything the wrong place, but...?
How do I make a columnlist of cards and pass the card into the onclick?

its really hard to help with your snippet code. can you add more?

I haven't known why you need to do this, maybe having an alternative solution, but basically, you can pass the widget itself like below:
final webCard1 = WebCard(
  date: 'June 11, 2024',
  time: '10AM-11AM',
  title: 'Blank',
  subTitle: 'GoToBlankPage',
  url: '',
  onCustomJoin: () => openpage(context, webCard1), // <------
);
final webCard2 = WebCard(
  date: 'June 12, 2024',
  time: '1PM-2PM',
  title: 'Brugal',
  subTitle: 'Brugal Rum',
  url: 'https://www.brugal.com',
  onCustomJoin: () => openpage(context, webCard2), // <------
);
ListView(
  children: [
    webCard1,
    webCard2,
  ],
);


It seemed to me that if I clicked the button that was on the card (the onCustomJoin bit), it would be nice to pass in the whole Card class.  Then if the handler wanted more info in the future, it would be easier to add that to the Card and then... available.
OTOH... I could have the App have the array of cards and just pass the index (which is what I was expecting Dart to do anyway)...
